# How do I get the value of a Spinner of another class? (Getting NullPointerException)

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, sharedpreferences, android-spinner

I have two classes `Settings` and `MainActivity`. I am trying to get the selected item of a spinner created at the `Settings` class from the `MainActivity` class.

I used `sharedpreferences` within the `Settings` activity to save the selected spinner value when the activity closes. This works.

To get the value from Settings activity while in MainActivity I use

```
public static Settings getlang = new Settings();
```

and

```
getlang.getLang1().getItemAtPosition(getlang.getLang1().getSelectedItemPosition());
```

`getLang1()` is a methode I created in the Settings activity that returns the Spinner itself.

The problem is, If I try to do this without opening the Settings activity first and directly going into the MainActivity I get the NullPointerException at this line

```
 getlang.getLang1().getItemAtPosition(getlang.getLang1().getSelectedItemPosition());
```

But If I first open the `Settings` activity and then go to `MainActivity` everything works fine.

How can I fix this?

Here is the `Settings` activity

```
public class Settings extends Activity {

    public SharedPreferences prefsSet;
    public String prefNameSet = "MyPrefSet";

    public static final String PREFS_NAME_SET = "SAVEDATASET";

    private static final String SPINNER1_STATE = "spinner1_state";

    public int language;

    public int userChoice;

    private static Spinner spinner1;
    private Button savesett;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.settings);

        savesett = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSaveSett);

        spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("FileName",
                MODE_PRIVATE);
        int spinnerValue = sharedPref.getInt("userChoiceSpinner", -1);
        if (spinnerValue != -1)
            // set the value of the spinner
            spinner1.setSelection(spinnerValue);

        spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int pos, long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                userChoice = spinner1.getSelectedItemPosition();
                SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("FileName",
                        0);
                SharedPreferences.Editor prefEditor = sharedPref.edit();
                prefEditor.putInt("userChoiceSpinner", userChoice);
                prefEditor.commit();
                Toast.makeText(
                        parent.getContext(),
                        "Chosen Language: "
                                + parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });

        savesett.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent ourIntent = new Intent(Settings.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(ourIntent);
            }

        });
    }

    public int getLang() {

        return userChoice;}

        public Spinner getLang1() {

            return Settings.spinner1;
    }
```

Comment: Could you post the `MainActivity` code? you say that the problem is there ...

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the Settings activity may or may not be instantiated. Given that it is your main activity that is trying to use it, it most likely never will be.

What you want to do is persist the value of the spinner in your preferences and not the index of the spinner item.

Consider the case of a user being able to use a spinner that selects how often they want a service to be checked by the app. The spinner choices are "1 minute", "5 minutes", "10 minutes", "15 minutes", "30 minutes", "1 hour".

When the preference is saved, we'll save 1, 5, 10, 15, 30, or 60.

The activity that uses this information will just get back an int that corresponds to how many minutes it should wait between refreshes.

Comment: Since you're dealing with language the simplest may be to save that language as a string. Then you read that string and act on it. My preference would be to use a constants class since it eliminates any typo problems. Since your issue here is a methodology problem, I've let you know the correct method to use. If you have a problem implementing it, ask a new question with your new code (or update this question with the new code).